# Naming convention of database models and view models

Tags: mobile

I have problem with my mobile application (I use Mvvm) - naming convention between models that I use for database (so classes with properties) and some part of abstract models that I use for my view models.

Example

I store in database 'Cars', so I have class called 'Cars' with properties like - Guid, Name, Color. In my view model I present on list those cars, so I will need collection of Cars which have properties like Name, IsSelected.

Of course I don't want to have one class in my project called 'Cars' with all properties, so I wonder if there is better option / naming convention than storing 'Cars' and 'CarsCollectionItem' in one folder 'Models' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think of it in terms of purpose:

- Say the content of your database is the reference, so you should just have a `DbSet<Car> Cars`.
- Now if you use MVVM, the Collections you use exist for some reason. The most generic reason would be to display them, so you could have `Collection<DisplayedCar> DisplayedCars`.

This is if you want to implement a façade to your Db object. The alternative approach would be to use Db objects in your view model.

```
var carsVm = new CarsViewModel();
var carVm = new CarViewModel() {Car = carFromDb};
carsVm.Cars.Add(carVm);
CarsView.DataModel = carsVm;
CarView.DataModel = carVm;
```

and then:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding MyCarVm}">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Car.Name}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this.